# How to add audio to Blender 2D animation?

Tags: animation, audio

All the tutorials I have seen for adding audio to a 2D animation in Blender involved using the video editor. Is there any way where you can just directly import audio to your animation?

Comment: What do you mean by directly? In Blender there is a Speaker object that can reproduce sounds during an animation

Comment: The tutorials I have seen showed the process of putting audio into your animation to be like this:
1. Import your animation into the video editor.
2. After you have done that, you can add audio to your animation.

I feel like importing your animation into the video editor is just an extra, unnecessary step. So, what I meant by directly is this: is there a way to import audio into your animation without having to import the animation into the video editor? Thanks!

Comment: You don't need to import the animation as a video in the VSE. You just add the audio on the frame you want it to start, and it'll come out with the animation (regardless of whether it's imported video, 3D, or 2D)

Answer (score 2):

In the Video Sequencer (shift f8), in the dropdown menus, under "Add" -> "Sound". You can cut it and move it around, the same as the video strips.

The sound should play on the same frames that they would on imported video (even if there's no "video", per say)

Answer (score 1):

In the top row you should have

*2D Animation* | *2D Full Canvas* | *Compositing* | *Rendering* | *+*

1. Click the "+" in the sub-menu of *Video Editing* click *Video Editing*.
2. In the *Video Editing* tab navigate to your sound file.
3. Drag and drop the sound file anywhere into the sequencer.

The sound file is directly in your animation.

Go back to the *2D Animation* tab and play your animation to see.

Comment: Also, make sure that in "Output", you have audio set to something other than "No Audio".